# Access a .env variable from a public script in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I have a hbs temnplate with a public script attached:

```
<h1>Hbs file</h1>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

Inside this script, I need the value stored on the `.env` file, but as it is a public script, `process` is not available:

```
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY // process is not defined
```

How can I access a .env variable from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

`process.env` are server-side vars. What you can do is when generating a view or URL append query string and then read that query string from public script

`/some-route/?some-var={process.env.someVar}`

Then in `script.js` you can get this query parameter

Or you can even generate `script.js` from server-side with values from process.